# Jquery code on load not firing

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have the following JQuery code in a external JS file linked into a 
usercontrol in .Net 1.1 webapp.

The usercontrol is a timesheet.

When the page loads it calls MonthChange and works fine in one page.

But now I want to load the timesheet/usercontrol into aother
webpage that pops up a in a new browser window for printing.

Problem is my MonthChange is not firing.

Any ideas why???

```
$(function() {

    MonthChange();
    //TestData();

    $('[class^=TSGridTB]').blur(function() {
        var day = GetDay($(this).attr('id'));
        var date = GetRowDate(day);
        var bgcolor = GetInputFieldColor(date, false);

        $(this).css("background-color", bgcolor);
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", bgcolor);
        //CalcHours($(this).get(0));
    });

    $('[class^=TSGridTB]').focus(function() {
        var day = GetDay($(this).attr('id'));
        var date = GetRowDate(day);
        var bgcolor = GetInputFieldColor(date, true);

        $(this).css("background-color", bgcolor);
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", bgcolor);
    });

    $('[id$=lstMonth]').change(function() {
        MonthChange();
    });         

});
```

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: make sure to use `$(document).ready()`. http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready

Answer (score 0):

without seeing further code, ensure that the selector is correct for the control in the new page.

The problem may be that the DOM has changed for the new page/window and JQuery does not yet know about it.

The [change event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change#fn)

> fires when a control loses the input
>   focus and its value has been modified
>   since gaining focus.

You might want to use the [live event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn):

> Binds a handler to an event (like
>   click) for all current - and future -
>   matched element.
>
> When you bind a "live" event it will
>   bind to all current and future
>   elements on the page (using event
>   delegation). For example if you bound
>   a live click to all "li" elements on
>   the page then added another li at a
>   later time - that click event would
>   continue to work for the new element
>   (this is not the case with bind which
>   must be re-bound on all new elements).

Comment: I may not have mentioned but the links to Jquery and all code are contained in the usercontrol. Just add to diffeent aspx page???

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the new web page has jQuery script includes?

Answer (score 0):

ensure you're using:

```
$(document).ready(
);
```

around your entire code block.  The $ alone often does not do the trick.